# How change div based on the child class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, infowindow

I'm working with google maps and I want to change the "info window" dimensions.

The gmaps js automatically generate this section:

[image]

I want to target the selected section that has no id or class to identify changing it's width. Then I thought that I need to use it's child div class named "gm-style-iw" like a reference to reach the other div above.

The idea would be something like this:

```
div < .gm-style-iw {
 width: 220px;
}
```

but we know that this '<' is not possible using css.

How can I do that?

Comment: There are some workarounds in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: yeah I saw some examples but in my case I want to use a class like a reference and not other elements like 'p' or 'a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably already aware, you'll need javascript for this to work as intended, and using jQuery's `.parent()`<sup>[ref](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)</sup>. method would probably be the most straight forward route to getting there.

Ref: [.parent() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Consider the below:

```
jQuery('.gm-style-iw').parent().css('width','220px');
```

On inspecting the element, you will notice that the inline `width` property has been applied and is *over-qualifying* the external `width` property rule set be the selector `.parent`.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
jQuery('.gm-style-iw').parent().css('width','220px');
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #dadada;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="gm-style-iw"><code>gm-style-iw</code></div>
</div>
```

It may be better practice to consider applying a class to these elements instead. As demonstrated above, *inline* style rules are quite persistent and are tricky to *over-qualify* without depending too much on the `!important` declaration.

Consider the following:

```
jQuery('.gm-style-iw').parent().addClass('contians-child');
```

Using a class selector as your identifier, you can circumvent this issue which may be sparing you some grey hairs down the line or wasted hours further on into your build.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
jQuery('.gm-style-iw').parent().addClass('contians-child');
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #dadada;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent.contians-child {
    width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="gm-style-iw"><code>gm-style-iw</code></div>
</div>
```